# Java - What is the best way to make a method that reads a file and outputs an array of what the file contains?

Tags: java

I am learning Java and in order to learn more about Java IO I am making a program to read a file path and return an array that contains everything from the file. I didn't want to specify that the data had to be integers so I've been working in strings. I'm running into an issue when I try to run a method returning an array. Is there a better way I should be writing this code?

```
import java.io.*;

public class OrganizeIO
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String sampleData[] = readFile("C://Users/Tweak/workspace/FileIO/resources/data.txt");
        int i = 0;
        while(sampleData[i] != null)
        {
            System.out.print(sampleData[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

public static String[] readFile(String file) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String currentLine;
    String[] data;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    int i = 0;
    while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(currentLine);
        currentLine = data[i];
        i++;
    }

    return data[];
}

}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: I would recommend http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of question.

Comment: *I'm running into an issue* - Well you have to tell us exactly what is the issue. Simply that sentence wouldn't help. Neither us, nor you.

Comment: Your file path looks wrong with the double `/` before `Users`

Comment: "return an array that contains everything from the file" That's badly specified. Why an array of Strings? Are you asusming the file is text? In which encoding? What does each element of the array contain? (a line?)

Comment: You never instantiate `String[] data` inside of readFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not storing anything in `data`, not to mention you haven't even initialized it (which results in a compilation error). You should be using a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) anyway, since you don't know how many lines you are going to read beforehand:

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    data.add(currentLine);
}

return data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);  // or just return the list?
```

Also, don't forget to close your `BufferedReader`:

```
br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for one it looks like you while loop should be

```
while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(currentLine);
    data[i] = currentLine;
    i++;
}
```

because you are returning nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work with the class **Scanner** to read the file and store it in a List.

```
// Open the file
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Tweak\\workspace\\FileIO\\resources\\data.txt"));

// Read the file line by line
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scanner.hasNext())
{
    result.add(scanner.nextLine());
}

scanner.close();

// If you want an array
String sampleData[] = result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how many lines you get, storing the read lines directly in an array is inappropriate, better take a `List` implementation for that:

```
public static List<String> readFile (File file, String encoding) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), encoding));
        List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.add(line);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Usage:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File("C://Users/Tweak/workspace/FileIO/resources/data.txt");
        List<String> lines = readFile(file, "UTF-8");
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

You can of course convert the `List` into a `String` array later, if that's what you want:

```
String[] linesArray = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
```